# Slow SQL query processing 5000 rows, which SQL Server tool can help me identify the issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm writing a heavy SQL query using SQL Server 2008. When the query process 100 rows, it finished instantly. When the query process 5000 rows it takes about 1.1 minutes.

I used the Actual Execution Plan to check its performance while it processing 5000 rows. The query contained 18 sub-queries,
there is no significate higher percentage of query cost shown in the plan, e.g. all around 0%,2%,5%,7%. The highest one is 11%. 
The screenshot below shows the highest process in the query. (e.g.94% of 11%)

[image: The screenshot below shows the highest process in the query. (e.g.94% of 11%)]

I also used the Client Statistic Tool, Trial 10 shows when it process 5000 rows, Trial 9 shows when it process 100 rows.

[image]

**Can anybody tell me where (or which SQL Server Tool) I can find the data/detail that indicates the slow process when the query execute 5000 rows?**

Add:
Indexes, keys are added.
The actual exe plan shows no comment and no high percentage on each sub-query.

I just found 'Activity Monitor' shows one sub-query's 'Average Duration' is 40000ms in 'Recent Expansive Queries', while the actual plan shows this query takes only 5% cost of total process.

Thanks

Comment: ***The main reason the process is slow?*** Probably your query. Are you joining on indexes?

Comment: 5000 rows is 50 times as big as 100 rows.  If the query finishes in a bit over a second, then 50 times as much data will finish in about a minute.  The result is not unexpected.  Without the query, it is rather hard to tell what is going on.  I find nested loop joins with no index to be the most suspicious elements of a plan.

Comment: Gordon is dead on.  You're likely losing the performance in your query that you haven't provided.  You have indexes but are they on fields that could help or hurt your performance?  To what degree is the db normalized?  All of these things impact performance, provide a little more info to get a thorough answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

For looking at performance, using the database tuning advisor and/or the missing index DMVs then examining the execution plan either in management studio or with something like sql sentry plan explorer should be enough to give you an indication where you need to make modifications.

Understanding the execution plan and how the physical operators relate to your logical operations is the biggest key to performance tuning, that and a good understanding of indexes and statistics.

I don't think there is any tool that will just automagically fix performance for you.

Answer (score 0):

While I do believe that learning the underpinnings of the execution plan and how the SQL Server query optimizer operates is an essential requirement to be a good database developer, and humans are still way better at diagnosing and fiddling with SQL to get it right than most tools native or third-party, there is in fact a tool which SQL Server Management Studio provides which can (sometimes) "automagically" fix performance for you:

[Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Which you can access via the ribbon menu under Query -> Analyze Query Using Database Engine Tuning Advisor OR (more helpfully) by selecting your query, right-clicking on the selection, and choosing Analyze Query using Database Engine Tuning Advisor, which gives the added bonus of automatically filtering down to only the database objects being used by your query.

All the tuning advisor actually does is investigates to see if there are any indexes or statistics that could be added to your objects. It then "recommends" them and you can apply none, some, or all of them if you choose.

*Caveat emptor alert!* All of its recommendations are geared towards making that particular query run faster, so what it definitely does **not** do is help make you good decisions about the consequences of adding an index that only gets used by maybe one or two queries but has to be updated constantly when you add data to your database. This is a SQL anti-pattern known as "index shotgunning" and is generally frowned upon by DBAs, who would rather see a query rewritten to take advantage of more useful indexes.